# String Sublist Manipulation

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
lis = {a,{{b,c},{d,e}},m,{p,q}}
```

Each single element of the list ("a" and "m" in this example) is followed by one or more sublists consisting of two elements ("{b,c}", "{d,e}" and "{p,q}" in this example).  I would like to tag each sublist pair with its preceding single element, turning the list into:

```
lis2 = {{b,c,a},{d,e,a},{p,q,m}}
```

I would be interested in an efficient way of doing this, and thank you in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split with a custom test is the first thing that comes to mind. And then Map to assemble the results.

```
lis = {a, {{b, c}, {d, e}}, m, {p, q}};
splitlis = Split[lis, Not[ListQ[#1]] && ListQ[#2] &];
mapfun[{x_, y_}] := Map[Append[#, x] &, Partition[Flatten[y], 2]];
Flatten[Map[mapfun, splitlis], 1]
```

(* {{b, c, a}, {d, e, a}, {p, q, m}} *)

Comment: There's nothing in the question to suggest that the initial split couldn't just be `Partition[lis, 2]`.

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `lis` has a recurring pattern of a `Symbol` followed by either a list of lists or a vector, two definitions must be employed for processing.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[{a_Symbol, b_?VectorQ}] := {Sequence @@ b, a}
f[{a_Symbol, b : {__List}}] := (Append[#, a] & /@ b ) // 
  Apply[Sequence]

SequenceReplace[lis
 , {a_Symbol, b_List} :> f[{a, b}]
 ]
```

> {{b, c, a}, {d, e, a}, {p, q, m}}

Answer (score 1):

**1.**

```
SequenceReplace[lis, 
  {{a_, b : {__List}} :> Splice[Append[a] /@ b], 
   {a_, b : {__}} :> Append[a] @ b}]
```

> ```
> {{b, c, a}, {d, e, a}, {p, q, m}}
> ```

**2.**

```
If[ListQ @ First @ #2, Splice[Append[#] /@ #2], Append[#] @ #2] & @@@ 
  Split[lis, ListQ @ #2 &]
```

> ```
> {{b, c, a}, {d, e, a}, {p, q, m}}
> ```

**3.**

```
{a___, b_, takeOver[c_], d___} ^:= 
   {a, If[ListQ @ First @ c, Splice[Append[b] /@ c], Append[b] @ c], d}

Replace[lis, x_List :> takeOver[x], {1}]
```

> ```
> {{b, c, a}, {d, e, a}, {p, q, m}}
> ```

Comment: The first two sublists are different compared to what's stated in the OP.

Comment: Thank you @Syed. I can't see a simple fix; so deleting for now.

Comment: The third variation is much above my current skill level. Thanks for this comprehensive answer.